# How to get response from foo.onload = function(){?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is triggered using .onload. I'd like return a value:

```
newImg.onload = function() {
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    if(height > width){
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(true);
        return true;
    }
 }
 newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload
```

Normaly I'd do something like

```
var foo = function(){...
```

but this doesn't work in this case. What should I do instead?

Comment: You have some spelling errors, `reurn false` and you should use as best practice to have `;` as delimiter.

Comment: If you're trying to get a response value, then you're missing the point of event-oriented programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous calls can not return values. You would need to use a callback like you would do in an Ajax request.

```
function loadImg (imgSrc, callback) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.onload = function() {
        var height = newImg.height;
        var width = newImg.width;
        if(height > width){
            console.log(false)
            if(callback) callback(false);
        } else {
            console.log(true)
            if(callback) callback(true);
        }
     };
     newImg.onerror = function () {
         if(callback) callback('error');
     };
     newImg.src = imgSrc;

}

loadImg("foo.gif", function(status) { console.log("Do Next Step"); })
```

Comment: great stuff! How would I use the callback?

Comment: Added a basic example of using the callback

Answer (score 0):

You have two options;

1. Set the value to another variable.

   ```
   var foo;

   newImg.onload = function () {
       foo = true;
   };

   // Sometime later read `foo`.
   ```

   ... albeit this is prone to disaster, as you can't guarantee *when* the variable will be set, as the image will take *some* amount of time to load.
2. A better option would be to call another function, pass the value you want to pass, and handle it accordingly then.

   ```
   newImg.onload = function () {
       foo(true);
   };

   function foo(result) {
       // do something with result
   }
   ```